# Selenium - MoveToElement() with transparent proxy

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, transparentproxy

I have element

```
public ArticlePage()
{
    PageFactory.InitElements(Browser.driver, this)
}

[FindsBy(How = How.Id, Using = "someId")]
private IWebElement btnTitleView { get; set; }
```

and action

```
Actions action = new Actions(Browser.driver);
action.MoveToElement(btnTitleView).Perform();
```

But when i try to run it, i will get error

> 'System.Reflection.TargetException' Object does not match target type.

I tried to locate this element by `Browser.driver.FindElement(By.Id("someId"))` and then it is working correctly. So, it is present and displayed.
Is it possible to use transparent proxy to perform `Actions`? Is there any other way to perform `MoveToElement()` like action on transparent proxy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to unwrap element which using transparent proxy you can use `IWrapsElement` interface which has `WrappedElement` property:

```
action.MoveToElement(((IWrapsElement)btnTitleView).WrappedElement).Build().Perform();
```

You may also want to have that cast included as extension method of `IWebElement` object:

```
public static class IWebElementExtensions
{
    public static IWebElement Unwrap(this IWebElement element)
    {
        return ((IWrapsElement)element).WrappedElement;
    }
}
```

Then the code of your action might look like this:

```
Actions action = new Actions(Browser.driver);
action.MoveToElement(btnTitleView.Unwrap()).Build().Perform();
```

I hope that answer will help you with your problem :)

Comment: And i was using reflection to do this. This is so easy!

Answer (score 2):

One way how to get around this is to use `IList<IWebElement>` and than use `foreach` or `LINQ` to manipulate the element. So you can use:

```
[FindsBy(How = How.Id, Using = "someId")]
private IList<IWebElement btnTitleView { get; set; }
...

Actions action = new Actions(Browser.driver);
action.MoveToElement(btnTitleView.First()).Perform();
```

or

```
foreach (var element in btnTitleView)
{
   Actions action = new Actions(Browser.driver);
   action.MoveToElement(element).Perform();
}
```