# Mouse hover not possible in Selenium Page Object Model with C#

Tags: javascript, c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, pageobjects

I need to hover over a menu option of a website, so that a context menu appears. So I tried both: using the Actions-Class and using the JavaScriptExecutor with a dedicated script in my Page-Object-Model-Selenium project with Pagefactory. But it turns out both of them throw exceptions in POM, while they don't in a non-POM Selenium project. I provided two quick examples, so you can compare the behaviors yourself.

Below is the version without POM, it works:

```
using System;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Support.Events;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Remote;
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Interactions;

namespace UnitTestProject1
{
[TestClass]
public class SimpleTest
{
    public static EventFiringWebDriver Driver { get; set; }

    [TestMethod]
    public void TestMethod1()
    {
        var caps = new DesiredCapabilities();
        caps.SetCapability("browserName", "internet explorer");
        SimpleTest.Driver = new EventFiringWebDriver(new RemoteWebDriver(new Uri("http://127.0.0.1:4444/wd/hub"), caps, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(120)));
        SimpleTest.Driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://www.stackoverflow.com");
        var element = SimpleTest.Driver.FindElement(By.Id("nav-questions"));

        // using Actions
        // does not throw an exception
        new Actions(SimpleTest.Driver).MoveToElement(element).Perform();

        // using JavaScript
        // does not throw an exception
        var mouseOverScript = @"if(document.createEvent){var evObj = document.createEvent('MouseEvents');evObj.initEvent('mouseover', true, false); arguments[0].dispatchEvent(evObj); } else if(document.createEventObject) { arguments[0].fireEvent('onmouseover'); }";
        ((IJavaScriptExecutor)SimpleTest.Driver).ExecuteScript(mouseOverScript, element);
    }

    [TestCleanup]
    public void Cleanup()
    {
        SimpleTest.Driver.Quit();
    }
}
}
```

And here is the version with POM, which only throws exceptions, even though everything else is the same as in the other example:

```
using System;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Support.Events;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Remote;
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Interactions;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Support.PageObjects;

namespace UnitTestProject1
{
[TestClass]
public class PomTest
{
    public PomTest()
    {
        var caps = new DesiredCapabilities();
        caps.SetCapability("browserName", "chrome");
        PomTest.Driver = new EventFiringWebDriver(new RemoteWebDriver(new Uri("http://127.0.0.1:4444/wd/hub"), caps, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(120)));
        PomTest.Driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://www.stackoverflow.com");
    }

    public static EventFiringWebDriver Driver { get; set; }

    [TestMethod]
    public void TestMethod1()
    {
        var page = new SoPage();
        page.HoverWithActions();
        page.HoverWithJS();
    }

    [TestCleanup]
    public void Cleanup()
    {
        PomTest.Driver.Quit();
    }
}

public class SoPage
{
    public SoPage()
    {
        PageFactory.InitElements(PomTest.Driver, this);
    }

    public void HoverWithActions()
    {
        // using Actions
        // throws System.Reflection.TargetException;
        new Actions(PomTest.Driver).MoveToElement(this.Element).Perform();
    }

    public void HoverWithJS()
    {
        // using JavaScript
        // throws System.ArgumentException
        var mouseOverScript = @"if(document.createEvent){var evObj = document.createEvent('MouseEvents');evObj.initEvent('mouseover', true, false); arguments[0].dispatchEvent(evObj); } else if(document.createEventObject) { arguments[0].fireEvent('onmouseover'); }";
        ((IJavaScriptExecutor)PomTest.Driver).ExecuteScript(mouseOverScript, this.Element);
    }

    [FindsBy(How = How.Id, Using = "nav-questions")]
    public IWebElement Element { get; set; }
}
}
```

The exceptions are this for Actions:

```
"System.Reflection.TargetException: Das Objekt stimmt mit dem Zieltyp nicht überein.
   bei System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.CheckConsistency(Object target)
   bei System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.InvokeArgumentsCheck(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
   bei System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
   bei OpenQA.Selenium.Support.PageObjects.WebDriverObjectProxy.InvokeMethod(IMethodCallMessage msg, Object representedValue)
   bei OpenQA.Selenium.Support.PageObjects.WebElementProxy.Invoke(IMessage msg)
   bei System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)
   bei OpenQA.Selenium.ILocatable.get_Coordinates()
   bei OpenQA.Selenium.Interactions.Internal.MouseAction.get_ActionLocation()
   bei OpenQA.Selenium.Interactions.MoveMouseAction.Perform()
   bei OpenQA.Selenium.Interactions.CompositeAction.Perform()
   bei OpenQA.Selenium.Interactions.Actions.Perform()
   bei UnitTestProject1.SoPage.HoverWithActions() in c:\\users\\lwa\\documents\\visual studio 2015\\Projects\\UnitTestProject1\\UnitTestProject1\\PomTest.cs:Zeile 50.
   bei UnitTestProject1.PomTest.TestMethod1() in c:\\users\\lwa\\documents\\visual studio 2015\\Projects\\UnitTestProject1\\UnitTestProject1\\PomTest.cs:Zeile 28."
```

And this for the JavaScriptExecutor:

```
System.ArgumentException: Argument is of an illegal typeOpenQA.Selenium.Support.Events.EventFiringWebDriver+EventFiringWebElement
Parametername: arg
   bei OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.ConvertObjectToJavaScriptObject(Object arg)
   bei OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.ConvertArgumentsToJavaScriptObjects(Object[] args)
   bei OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.ExecuteScriptCommand(String script, String commandName, Object[] args)
   bei OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.ExecuteScript(String script, Object[] args)
   bei OpenQA.Selenium.Support.Events.EventFiringWebDriver.ExecuteScript(String script, Object[] args)
   bei UnitTestProject1.SoPage.HoverWithJS() in c:\\users\\lwa\\documents\\visual studio 2015\\Projects\\UnitTestProject1\\UnitTestProject1\\PomTest.cs:Zeile 58.
   bei UnitTestProject1.PomTest.TestMethod1() in c:\\users\\lwa\\documents\\visual studio 2015\\Projects\\UnitTestProject1\\UnitTestProject1\\PomTest.cs:Zeile 29."
```

I am using C# in Visual Studio 2015 with the packages Selenium.WebDriver and Selenium.Support both in version 3.3, there is a bug that prevents me from using 3.4 (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43765261/selenium-remotewebdriver-c-sharp-system-invalidoperationexception)). My Selenium Server Standalone is 3.4.0. The behaviors is the same for Chrome, Firefox and Internet Explorer.

Does anyone have an idea of how to make hovering possible in a POM-Project in C#?

Comment: Can you check in debug that this.Element has been properly initialized when it's passed to the script/action?

Comment: In the first example I can look at the elements in debug without problem, while in the POM example this.Element shows an error "Obtaining the runtime type of a transparent proxy is not supported in this context.", when viewed in debug. So I am guessing it is not initialized properly, how do I change that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found two workarounds for this. You can either discard the FindsByAttribute and define a property getter yourself

```
public IWebElement Element => PomTest.Driver.FindElement(By.Id("nav-questions"));
```

or instead of an IWebElement you can use an IList of IWebElements and then refer to the first Element of the list, credit for this option goes to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35936035/selenium-movetoelement-with-transparent-proxy).
This will be the variant I am using, and it looks like this:

```
public void HoverWithActions()
{
    // using actions
    // now it works :)
    new Actions(PomTest.Driver).MoveToElement(this.Elements.First()).Perform();
}

public void HoverWithJS()
{
    // using Javascript
    // now it works :)
    var mouseOverScript = @"if(document.createEvent){var evObj = document.createEvent('MouseEvents');evObj.initEvent('mouseover', true, false); arguments[0].dispatchEvent(evObj); } else if(document.createEventObject) { arguments[0].fireEvent('onmouseover'); }";
    ((IJavaScriptExecutor)PomTest.Driver).ExecuteScript(mouseOverScript, this.Elements.First());
}

[FindsBy(How = How.Id, Using = "nav-questions")]
public IList<IWebElement> Elements { get; set; }
```